# axml Design view will not load - Custom Controls disabled xamarin.android

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin.android

I'm currently using vs 2015 and my project had been running fine then all of a sudden my layout design view will not display and I get the following message

custom controls disabled there was a problem with the rendering process

I have not changed or deleted any files.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to why this is happening?

Comment: Having the same issue using Xamarin Studio for Mac :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Using Xamarin Studio Community for Mac]

I kinda fixed it by fixing another issues within my code.

There was a part were I was trying to access a Resource that didn't exist, removed that line, cleaned the code and built it into my device. After that all the `.axml` started to load successfully, there is still the warning at the bottom saying

> "Custom controls disabled. Please upgrade your version of
>   Xamarin.Android to enable custom controls."

but at least the `.axml` files are now loading.